# Need help with complex texture mapping

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I'm new to Blender but have used various 3D tools in past (Alias Wavefront, 3DS4... yes, i'm old). I want to experiment with some new livery for my teams race car. (https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCw93XfcHZZ-ZLkKmCZR6dYw).

I've purchased a nice model from https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/1984-volvo-245-wagon-3d-model-1771691 and learned a little about UV mapping.

It has resulted in this model creating this map.

[image]

What I started to do was export the image and edit in Photoshop. I want to add a logo to the side of the car, something like...

[image]

Now the challenge is that the UV map breaks the door into three different areas. If you look at the image above of the Blender UX, you can see how the blue line ends up in three difference places on the UV map. (Circled in green).

I tried hitting the unwrap item in the UV menu, and this gave me a slightly different map. This time the door is indeed all in the same place, BUT a headlight map is now over the top of it as well... as you can see from the image below.
[image]

This is making my editing in Photoshop a challenge to get the logo to sit correctly on the door. I tried following a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=56AAMGYIVsQ) for layering multiple textures on a model so I can apply the logo as a separate image. But it seems it's complicated to add many different textures, in different places, to a model.

Can anyone advise me on the right approach here? Assuming there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Hello and welcome. You could start with the basics and because your model does not have any texture, you could unwrap the UV's again https://youtu.be/Y7M-B6xnaEM?t=202

Comment: Is there a way to modify / simplify the model to improve the unwrap algorithms? It looks like seaming might also be a way to do this.

Comment: I updated the original post with another effort, now the UV map has parts of the model overlayed on top of each other.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to edit the texture in Photoshop?

Comment: Actually no, that's just how i've done things in the past. Is there a better way? Oooh does blender have a good way to add images onto a texture?

Comment: Yes, you can use a logo image and stencil it on the model. Or create another UV map and mix the logo into the car paint.

Comment: Can you give a link to a tutorial of how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution.
Leave the UV unwrap as it was originally (without overlapping UVs.)
Then use Blender's [quick edit](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/sculpt_paint/texture_paint/tool_settings/options.html#external) tool to capture a side view of the car and edit it in an external program.

After you apply the quick edit, the image will be projected onto the car and stored in the texture according to the UV map.

Here is a link to a tutorial on YouTube that you might find helpful: [Blender Secrets - Texture Painting With Quick Edit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kqnF3LCm-cA)